# Prove the following implications, and for each draw Venn diagram.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In what follows X is a set, A, B, C, etc., are subsets of X. The complement
of a subset Y ⊂ X is denoted $Y^c$
. Prove the following implications, and
for each draw Venn diagram.

1) A ⊆ B ⇒ A ⊆ (B ∪ C)

2) $A$ $⊂$ ($B_1$ ∪ $B_2$), (A ∩ $A_1$ ∩ $B_1$) ⊆ C,  (A ∩ $A_2$ ∩ $B_2$) ⊆ C ⇒ (A ∩ $A_1$ ∩ $A_2$) ⊆ C.

3) A ⊂ B ⇒ (A ∩ ($B^c$ ∪ $C$)) ⊆ C.

4) (A ∩ B) ⊂ C ⇒ A ⊆ ($B^c$ ∪ C).

Comment: Well, what did you try? Where is the problem?

Comment: that#s the problem, I don't know where to start these questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning. How do you show $X$ is a subset of $Y$? By definition you need to take an element in $X$ and prove it must be an element of $Y$. For example, in the first part you need to show that $A\subseteq (B\cup C)$. So take an element $x\in A$. You know $A\subseteq B$ and hence $x\in B$. But if $x\in B$ then $x\in (B\cup C)$. That's it. Now try the other exercises.

Comment: but how would you do 2)?

Comment: Again, what do you need to prove? That $A\cap A_1\cap A_2\subseteq C$. So take an element $x\in A\cap A_1\cap A_2$. Then $x\in A$. But $A\subseteq B_1\cup B_2$ and hence $x$ is in $B_1$ or in $B_2$. What happens if it is in $B_1$? What about if it is in $B_2$?

Comment: is it the same to say A⊆B1∪B2 and  A ⊂ (B1 ∪ B2) ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Well, at least in most books $\subseteq$ and $\subset$ is the same thing. But in some book by $A\subset B$ they mean that $A$ is a subset of $B$ and is not equal to $B$. Just like the difference between $\leq$ and $<$. Anyway, without any doubt it means $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: but in question 3) i start by taking  x ∈ (A ∩ (Bc ∪ C) then  x ∈ A and A ⊂ B then x ∈ B, which means that x does not belong to B complement, which also means that x does not belong to (Bc  ∪ C). where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that $X\cup Y$ means that $x\in X$ or $x\in Y$. Don't get confused between union and intersection. Union means that $x$ needs to be at least in one of these sets, not necessary in both. So you got it right: $x\in B^c\cup C$ but $x\notin B^c$. Hence $x\in C$, so the problem is solved.